permission denied when accessing table created by application user
I've added an R/O user:
CREATE USER ro_user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'xxx';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE my_db TO ro_user;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO ro_user;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO ro_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO ro_user;

When the table is created under the root account, the ro_name can select from these tables.
However, I have an application user app_user, which also creates tables, i.e.
CREATE TABLE public.test (
    code        char(5)
)

In this case ro_name does not have the select permission. Is there a fix for that ?
I need to grant select privileges on all tables in schema public regardles of who created these tables

From what I read, that's how it works. You either set an internal step procedure that any dev or DBA that adds objects (relevant to the R/O users using whatever internal company criteria) also adds right for the ROUs, either you try a less conventional but "automatic" way of monitoring each DDL at your EOD and assign access to them the next day (I don't recommend this, as you might not want to add access to just about any table, but maybe you can do some prefix or suffix rule). Also, I recommend you use roles for ROUs rather than "hardcoded" users. That way you won't need to repeat commands.
